# Port 5432 doesn't listen on Raspberry PI

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi, port, raspberry-pi3, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to run postgresql 9.4 on my Raspberry PI 3, but without success.

My `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all     all     10.0.1.0/24     md5
```

And this on `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

When I start the service and get the status:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service postgresql start
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-03-02 22:51:27 UTC; 29s ago
  Process: 2840 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2840 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 02 22:51:27 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

I'm getting only ssh port:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      577/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      577/sshd
```

From my mac I try to connect:

```
❯  psql -h 10.0.1.4 jdmclub_development pguser
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "10.0.1.4" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can anybody help me?

**EDIT**

Postgresql logs says:

```
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-1] LOG: invalid value for parameter "lc_messages": "en_GB.UTF-8" 
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-2] LOG: invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "en_GB.UTF-8" 
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-3] LOG: invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "en_GB.UTF-8" 
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-4] LOG: invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "en_GB.UTF-8" 
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-5] FATAL: configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

Comment: How is the memory setting for your postgresql database? Running an database like that in a raspberry is an overkill to the device, I feel.

Comment: What about postgresql logs? What they tell ?

Comment: 2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-1] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_messages": "en_GB.UTF-8"
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-2] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "en_GB.UTF-8"
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-3] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "en_GB.UTF-8"
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-4] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "en_GB.UTF-8"
2017-03-02 23:18:06 UTC [3993-5] FATAL:  configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf" contains errors

Comment: There is your problem the postgresql didn't start at all. You have configurations error.

Comment: damn how i fix that?

Comment: Take a look at these threads it may help: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1692475.html and http://askubuntu.com/questions/501181/how-to-change-fix-systems-locale-when-you-setup-in-a-language-not-official-in-y

Comment: works! thanks all, and sorry.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Please add the steps you did to make it work as an answer. I just pointed you in the right direction, your actual answer may help others.

Comment: The LC_ settings are certainly a problem. (en_GB.UTF-8 is not recognised) The rest of the configuration is also more-or-less non-standard. {max_connections,shared_buffers,work_mem,random_page_cost,effective_cache_size}

Answer (score 1):

To fix it with the next steps:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

1. 4 Localisation Options
2. Select
3. I1 Change Locale
4. Select
5. Check en_GB.UTF-8 UTF8
6. OK
7. C.UTF-8
8. OK

And try to start postgres service again.

This worked for me.

Comment: anyone have any idea why this would work?